# Using dio in flutter to get distance between source and destination

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';


const apiKey = "my api key";

class DistanceController{


  void getDistance({LatLng source, LatLng destination})async{
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  Response response = await dio.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=1.341786,103.826009&destinations=1.332747%2C,103.919106&key=$apiKey");
  print('getiing distance:');
  print(response.data);
  }
}
```

The above is my code and my output is :
{destination_addresses: [], origin_addresses: [], rows: [{elements: [{status: NOT_FOUND}]}], status: OK}

My question is how can I get a distance in m/km between the 2 LatLng I give in my request? If dio doesn't return me the distance, is there another package I can use?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have set up a real API key already. It is functioning and I did not put it in the code above

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the function below; so long as you have to source and destination LongLat.

```
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;


  double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 + 
          c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * 
          (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }
```

Credit to [@westdabestdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6948095/westdabestdb)